# How To Make Sure A User Inputted Password Matches The Username Registered To That Password?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am curious how to make an example program where a user registers ( I know how to do this part) but when the user registers and the username gets added to a list or dictionary that they have to much it can't be another user's password because if I do "if x in x:" because it will allow another use's password to give access to a different user. I just want the correct data to match.

```
#Example

users = ["bob", "joe"]
passwords = ["example1", "example2"]

ex1 = input("What is your username?")
if ex1 in users:
    ex2 = input("enter your password")
if ex2 in passwords:
    print("access granted")
#With this code any password will work with any user,
#I want the registered user's password to have to be the password they registered with
```

Comment: Use a dictionary to map the user names to their passwords, `d = dict(zip(users,passwords))` and then access passwords like `d['bob']`

Comment: You're missing the idea of *your password*, rather than just *a password*. Get the password for the matching user, then check against that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a Dictionary, that way you can link a password to a user.

```
users = ["bob", "joe"]
passwords = ["example1", "example2"]

# d = {'bob' : 'example1', 'joe' : 'example2'}
# An example how to zip your lists into a dictionary
d = dict(zip(users, passwords))

ex1 = input("What is your username?")
if ex1 in users:
    ex2 = input("enter your password")

# How to use your dict to check if the password matches the user
if ex2 == d[ex1]:
    print("access granted")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
users = {"bob": "example1", "joe": "example2"}
ex1 = raw_input("What is your username?: ")
if ex1 in users:
    ex2 = raw_input("enter your password: ")
if ex2 == users.get(ex1):
    print("access granted")
```

Comment: Did you read the comments and other answers? Did you read the Python 3 tag? You know the `.keys()` call is redundant?